# How to connect wired ubuntu server to network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, wired

I checked a few threads and followed some steps but still having problem

I have a **Cisco E2000 WiFi router**, to which I have Mac wireless connected

From Mac, I visit `192.168.1.1` and I can see something like
Automatic Configuration by DHCP

```
IP address 192.168.1.1
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Device name SmallFlamingo

Start IP Address: 192.168.1.100
Maximum Number of Users: 50
IP Address Range:   192 .168.1.100 to 149
```

WiFi wireless and Mac no problem, can connect to internet

I just got a Ubuntu server (pre-configured some normal way for a specific task), which I connected to WiFi router via Ethernet cable

Some info regarding the server

```
uname -a
Linux HK2DR22 2.6.32-21-server #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 09:17:34 UTC 2010 x86_4 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
NO LSB modules are available
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release: 10.04

ping 192.168.1.1
connect: Network is unreachable

more /etc/network/interfaces
# some comment lines I skipped since I need type the output
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
pre-up iptables-restore --noflush < /etc/iptables.custom

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.201.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
address 192.168.202.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
address 192.168.203.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth4
iface eth4 inet static
address 192.168.204.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth5
iface eth5 inet static
address 192.168.205.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

How can I connect the server to network? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You shouldn't be using an 8 year old OS that has been out of support (and security updates) for 3 years.

That said, your machine seems to have 6 network cards configured, and all you need to do is to plug the correct one in - you seem to have used one of the others.

With `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/speed` you can check, if the DHCP NIC is connected and at what speed.

Comment: Alternatively, use `ip link` to display the link state of all NICs and see at a glance which one is connected.

Comment: "_You shouldn't be using an 8 year old OS that has been out of support (and security updates) for 3 years._" It almost fits on [retrocomputing.se]. :)

Comment: @Eugen Rieck you're right. I plugged into the wrong card. The server OS is pre-configured. Thanks!